# Are members of the Suicide Squad released with bombs still in their heads?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

In the Arrowverse, the 2015 film and at least one animated movie, before sending members of the Suicide Squad on missions Waller has explosives implanted in their skull so should they turn on her they can be taken out by remote. But if a member of the squad works off his prison sentence, is the bomb removed on his release? And if not, what keeps Waller from detonating it if the former convict slips back into his old, criminal habits?

Comment: "what keeps Waller from detonating it" - this is Amanda Waller. Nothing keeps her from anything she wants to do.